# How does the | operator work?

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation

I am feeling confused with the | operator in C++. I have code to transfer the data which read from a MCU. The high 8 bits are seperated from low 8 bits. And the data(the BUF in code) store the complement number. So I use `(BUF[1] << 8) | BUF[0]` to get my raw data. However, the result is a bit strange. For example, the now code get `d1=-84`. As the pic shows, why doesn't the `|` operator get results as I want?
[image]

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cmath>
#include<iostream>

int main() {
    signed char BUF[2];
    BUF[0] = -84;
    BUF[1] = -2;
    short d1;
    d1 = (BUF[1] << 8) | BUF[0];  // | operator
    std::cout << d1 << std::endl;
    std::cin.get();
}
```

Comment: To begin with you need to actually know which programming language you are programming in... this is not C but C++.

Comment: `(-2 << 8)` is 1111 1111 1111 1111 1110 0000 0000 (32 bits). `-84` is 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1010 1100 (32 bits). OR them together and you get 1111 1111 1111 1111 1010 1100 (32 bits) which is `-84`. To get 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1110 1010 1100, you can do `(-2 << 8) | (-84 & 0xff)`.

Comment: Isn't there also a problem with shifting an 8 bit element by 8 bits (unless this is one of those exotic 9-bit char systems)?

Comment: @ChristianGibbons The operands are promoted to `int`.

Comment: @molbdnilo I suppose I should have figured as much.  One of these days I'll get a better read on when integer promotions occur.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot left-shift negative numbers, doing so invokes undefined behavior: anything can happen. Similarly, right-shifting negative numbers is also a bad idea, since that can result in either arithmetic or logical right shift.

You have to cast the variable to unsigned type, shift, then convert back. For example:

```
d1 = ((uint32_t)BUF[1] << 8) ...
```

Answer (score 3):

The behaviour on left shifting a negative number is *undefined*, and prior to C++14 you are vulnerable to different complementing schemes for a `signed char`. (From C++14 `signed char` and `char` if it's `signed` must be 2's complement.)

For an easy life, write merely

```
BUF[1] * 256 + BUF[0]
```

noting that the *type* of this expression is an `int`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In my computer(windows 10, Visual Studio 2015 v140 x64), `BUF[1] * 256 + BUF[0]` gets `1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111 1101 1010 1100` which is `-596`. The high bits(9th and 10th) get some problems. please refer to the answer of @Lundin.